# can we show that for all $n>0$ in N it exists $(p;q) \in N$ such as $n=2^p*(2*q+1)$

Tags: induction, integers

with $(p;q)\in N^2$

I have tried to prove that p is the greatest integer in $A=[{m \in N / n\space is\space a\space multiple\space of \space2^m}]$ but didn't know how to proceed

Also, we can show this by induction; starting by supposing that the affirmation is correct $\forall k\in ]0;n]$

And implying that $n+1=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{k=n}k$ but I'm curious about how to go from this to proving that $\exists (p_{k+1};q_{k+1})$ such as $n+1=2^{p_{k+1}}*(2*q_{k+1}+1)$

Comment: Are you attempting to prove that every (positive) integer is an odd number times a nonnegative power of $2$?

Comment: @Acehardwell If $n=2$, what would be $p$ and $q$?

Comment: $4 = 2^2 (2 \cdot 0 + 1)$ and $5 = 2^0 (2 \cdot 2 + 1)$.

Comment: $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @PierreCarre Depends on the definitions.

Comment: If $0 \notin \mathbb N$, then the statement is false, but usually we take $0 \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I wouldn't say we *usually* take $0\in\mathbb N$, I would say we often do. But we also often don't.

Comment: @MishaLavrov "Usually" I don't take $0\in \mathbb{N}$ and I believe  I'm not alone... But this is just a mater of eventually clarifying the statement.

Comment: @5xum It's true; this semester, I'm leaving $0$ out of my $\mathbb N$ to be consistent with the textbook. But it's making me cry a little on the inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of going about proving the statement is not by induction, but rather by proving:

1. The set $P=\{x, 2^x| n\}$ is bounded above.
2. From that, conclude that it has a maximum element. Define $p$ as that maximum element.
3. $\frac{n}{2^p}$ is an odd number.

---

However, if you really want to go by induction, then separate two cases:

1. If $n+1$ is odd, then clearly, $p=0$ and $q=\frac{n}{2}$
2. If $n+1$ is even, consider the number $n'=\frac{n}{2}$. Is the number smaller than or equal to $n$? If so, can you apply the indunction hypothesis on it? What does the hypothesis tell you?